# Vue warn - Cannot read property indexOf of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuesax

At first to point, i have seen a lot of similar problems here on stackoverlow, but no one is relatable to this example...

I am working on Vue JS project + Laravel so everything was going smoothly but suddenly i got error that cannot solve (from my perspective everything is correct).

Basically I am using Vuesax library too.

So i have projects table with edit button `@click="editProject(project)` and the called method is...

```
editProject(project) {
    let membersIds = []
    let teamsIds = []

    project.members.forEach(member => membersIds.push(member.id))
    project.groups.forEach(team => teamsIds.push(team.id))

    this.editProjectData = {
        name: project.name,
        start_date: project.start_date,
        deadline: project.deadline,
        members: membersIds,
        teams: teamsIds,
        status: project.status,
        priority: project.priority,
        description: project.description,
        color: project.color,
        visibility: project.visibility
    }
    this.showEditProject = true
}
```

So in that moment... `showEditProject = true` will bring me the modal with the form filled by `props` data

```
<transition name="slide-right">
    <EditProject :project-data="editProjectData" :all-statuses="allStatuses" :all-priorities="allPriorities" :all-colors="allColors" :all-members="allMembers" :all-teams="allTeams" v-show="showEditProject"/>
</transition>
```

So I am looping through the data (statuses, colors, priorities, members, teams) and filling the form.

So with priorities there is no any problem, also with statuses and colors, but i have problem with members and teams.

```
<div class="w-full mb-3">
    <vs-select multiple :label="$t('work.projects.edit-project-modal.members')" v-model="projectData.members" color="#91C959" style="width: 100%;">
        <vs-select-item :key="member.id" :value="member.id" :text="member.firstname + ' ' + member.lastname" v-for="member in allMembers" />
    </vs-select>
</div>
```

Same approach is for all of them, but error appear only when members and teams are available - if i comment them - no problem.
I get 4 errors per member/team (bellow)

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

found in

---> <VsSelectItem>
       <VsSelect>
         <Modal> at resources/js/components/Modal.vue
           <EditProject> at resources/js/components/Work/Projects/EditProject.vue
             <Projects> at resources/js/views/Projects.vue
               <App> at resources/js/App.vue
                 <Root>
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Proxy.vsSelectItemvue_type_template_id_681b8e3f_lang_html_render (app.js:52554)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (app.js:41589)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (app.js:42107)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:42520)
    at new Watcher (app.js:42509)
    at mountComponent (app.js:42114)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (app.js:47091)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (app.js:50000)
    at init (app.js:41162)
    at createComponent (app.js:44017)
```

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

found in

---> <VsSelectItem>
       <VsSelect>
         <Modal> at resources/js/components/Modal.vue
           <EditProject> at resources/js/components/Work/Projects/EditProject.vue
             <Projects> at resources/js/views/Projects.vue
               <App> at resources/js/App.vue
                 <Root>
```

```
app.js:39934 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Proxy.vsSelectItemvue_type_template_id_681b8e3f_lang_html_render (app.js:52554)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (app.js:41589)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (app.js:42107)
    at Watcher.get (app.js:42520)
    at new Watcher (app.js:42509)
    at mountComponent (app.js:42114)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (app.js:47091)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (app.js:50000)
    at init (app.js:41162)
    at createComponent (app.js:44017)
```

Data is displayed without any problem - so form is properly filled but console i full with the previously explained errors.

UPDATE:
Props in EditProject Component (Modal)

```
props: {
    projectData: {},
    allStatuses: {},
    allColors: {},
    allPriorities: {},
    allMembers: {},
    allTeams: {}
}
```

Members and Teams pictures bellow
[image: Parent component]

[image: Child component]

Comment: Do you have the "vue devtools" extension? i would recommend you to look there and see that the you are passing the correct props, perhaps you are passing 'undefined' instead of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically after good review and research of the code, i found that `EditProject` modal is displayed but because there is no data passed, it cause the error while trying to loop undefined members and teams.

So simple solution, to prevent `EditProject` component/modal to be loaded, i have added also `v-if="showEditProject"`

```
<transition name="slide-right">
    <EditProject v-if="showEditProject" v-show="showEditProject" :project-data="editProjectData" :all-statuses="allStatuses" :all-priorities="allPriorities" :all-colors="allColors" :all-members="allMembers" :all-teams="allTeams"/>
</transition>
```